# Serving ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 files from ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, character-encoding, iis-6

We have a large site with thousands of static html files. Some of them are ISO-8859-1, others are UTF-8 (with and without byte order marks).

The web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If I change the `fileEncoding` to `"ISO-8859-1"` it works for both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8  **if there is a byte order mark**. We are trying to avoid manually checking and adding byte order marks to files that do not have them. Is there any way to accomplish this?

The files have the charset meta tag. Can we make the server read that to determine the file encoding?

**EDIT**

If I remove the wildcard application mapping to aspnet_isapi.dll the files are served correctly. Is there any way to have the wildcard match everything except for .html?

Comment: You could just run a script that converts all pages to UTF-8

Comment: We have hundreds of contributors who are constantly changing files. Keeping up with every file change would be a problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need a CMS where users are prevented from posting the head tag or any headers for that matter and thus are prevented from setting the encoding.

Comment: @Thomas. We have one, but the static files are from the pre-CMS days and will eventually be converted.

Answer (score 0):

You could automate the checking of the files to see if they contain said characters / if they are utf-8.

This is a piece of code which pops up while googling that purpose [found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/97c51c2c-3d5b-44f6-a87d-811ba9caf4d8):

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = null; 
System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, 
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read); 
if (file.CanSeek) 
{ 
    byte[] bom = new byte[4]; // Get the byte-order mark, if there is one 
    file.Read(bom, 0, 4); 
    if ((bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) || // utf-8 
        (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe) || // ucs-2le, ucs-4le, and ucs-16le 
        (bom[0] == 0xfe && bom[1] == 0xff) || // utf-16 and ucs-2 
        (bom[0] == 0 && bom[1] == 0 && bom[2] == 0xfe && bom[3] == 0xff)) // ucs-4 
    { 
        enc = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII; 
    } 

    // Now reposition the file cursor back to the start of the file 
    file.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin); 
} 
else 
{ 
    // The file cannot be randomly accessed, so you need to decide what to set the default to 
    // based on the data provided. If you're expecting data from a lot of older applications, 
    // default your encoding to Encoding.ASCII. If you're expecting data from a lot of newer 
    // applications, default your encoding to Encoding.Unicode. Also, since binary files are 
    // single byte-based, so you will want to use Encoding.ASCII, even though you'll probably 
    // never need to use the encoding then since the Encoding classes are really meant to get 
    // strings from the byte array that is the file. 

    enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII; 
}
```

Comment: That will only detect UTF-8 with a byte order mark. Many of the files do not have it.